# MiniMagick's "strip" function makes picture filesize bigger

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, strip, minimagick

I have used MiniMagick to compress JPEG files.

With [`strip` function](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/135), I want to get rid of EXIF from image. So, I do:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("my_picture.jpg")
image.strip
image.write("my_picture_small.jpg")
```

but sometimes the size of `my_picture_small.jpg` is bigger than `my_picture.jpg`.

However, when I don't use the `strip` function, like

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("my_picture.jpg")
# image.strip
image.write("my_picture_small.jpg")
```

`my_picture_small.jpg`'s size is smaller.

That situation happened with some picture deal with Photoshop and in my CentOS computer, but run well with my Macbook. I don't know why stripping some information led to more storage.

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found that ImageMagick will recompress image even if it with any arguments, such as

```
convert image.jpg new_image.jpg
```

new_image.jpg will be different from image.jpg more or less. If image.jpg is from a phone or camera or a image processing tools, the degree of difference is also different.

So compress images with MiniMagick or Rmagick that use ImageMagick as there system support, just do `convert -strip image.jpg new_image.jpg` may led to a unexpected result, avoid to use MiniMagick command if there is no need to greatly compress file.